# Comparing Strings while reading a file with Scanner .hasNext(), .next

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, equals

I am trying to make a little Highscore for my Programm. The programm has a LogFile, i want to read that file and determine the winner. Because my programm has a few issues, you can answer the same question over and over again, and get credits for it. 
With the code bellow I tried to prevent a cheated score. I tried to compare the third, fourth and fifth String, which represents the calculation you have to solve. I want to ignore the count of the highscore when the next line has the same calculation
Can someone help me with this ? I just get a bunch of errors.

Thanks for your time and help.

```
public int readFile() {
    String score = null;
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String a = scan.next();
        String b = scan.next();
        String c = scan.next();
        String d = scan.next();
        String e = scan.next();
        String f = scan.next();
        String g = scan.next();
        String h = scan.next();
        String i = scan.next();

        if (c.equals(scan.next()) && d.equals(scan.next()) && e.equals(scan.next())) {
        } else {
            temp = Integer.parseInt(i);
            if (temp > highscore) {
                highscore = temp;
            }
        }

    }
    return highscore;
}
```

**Textfile :**

```
    014/07/29 08:25:15  95 + 80 4       false       -171        0
    2014/07/29 08:25:15 95 + 80 4       false       -171        0
    2014/07/29 08:25:49 8 * 3   24      true        0       1
    2014/07/29 08:25:49 8 * 3   24      true        0       2
    2014/07/29 08:25:49 8 * 3   24      true        0       3
    2014/07/29 08:25:50 8 * 3   24      true        0       4
    2014/07/29 08:25:50 8 * 3   24      true        0       5
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014/07/28"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at mathe.Highscore.readFile(Highscore.java:42)
    at mathe.Gui$TestActionListener.actionPerformed(Gui.java:231)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: beacause OP says u can answer the same question over and over again, and get credits for it and has provided no stack trace

Comment: *I just get a bunch of errors*: no, you don't. Each error you get comes with a precise message explaining what and where the problem is. Not reading them, and not posting them is the error.

Comment: Reformat your data file; have only single spaces between the entries. Then, use `String[] entry = scan.nextLine().split(" ");`... This way you can just access the  calculation as `entry[2], [3], ...` Read ahead the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep using scan.next in your conditional statements, your scanner will scan for the next value. I think you want to get the next value and use for your comparison instead.

```
public int readFile() {
    String score = null;
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String a = scan.next();
        String b = scan.next();
        String c = scan.next();
        String d = scan.next();
        String e = scan.next();
        String f = scan.next();
        String g = scan.next();
        String h = scan.next();
        String i = scan.next();

        String nextVal = scan.next();

        if (c.equals(nextVal) && d.equals(nextVal) && e.equals(nextVal)) {
        } else {
            temp = Integer.parseInt(i);
            if (temp > highscore) {
                highscore = temp;
            }
        }

    }
    return highscore;
}
```

I hope this helps.
Cheers..!

Comment: sadly no, same errors.
the text-file hast 9 seperated Strings, id like to compare the 3,4 and 5 String of line 1 with the same Strings on line 2.

Comment: If you want to compare the previous line, declare 3 variables outside the loop, similar to score here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to call scan.next() in an if statement.  The second scan.next will only be called if the first equals is true and so on for the second one, so it is very easy to mix up what columns you're trying to read.  Move those scan.next out of the if statement for starters.

From the error message, you are calling `Integer.parseInt(i);` on a date string.

It looks like you are trying to find the largest number in the file?  What you should be doing is storing the highest int, which is declared outside the loop.  e.g.

```
int Highscore = 0;
while (...) {
   .... 

  int num = Integer.parseInt(i);
  if (num > Highscore) {
    Highscore = num;
  }
```

If you get my drift.

Comment: I believe this should be a comment.

Comment: It does help with the code, but it's hard to say what the problem is exactly, to answer.  I would bet it probably does answer the question though.

Comment: And how do i compare those Strings if not with an if-statement?

Comment: See my edit.  Make use of the existing variables, not by calling scan.next extra times.

Comment: @Geryones I'm adding an answer.

Comment: That with the highest number works, the problem is the camparison of the calculation. i try to compare string 3,4 and 5 which represents the calculation.if you answer a question you can spam the check button and cheat witch highscore. i tried to elliminate the problem by checking the three strings wich make up the calculaton. i dont know what the date is doing there, cause i aint touching it, that would be string a and b

Comment: If your data file has 9 columns, you should only call scan.next 9 time inside the while loop.  You are calling it 10 to 12 times because of the additional calls to scan.next.  Try printing the value of each variable, or using a debugger to view the values.